# How can I tell which driver my system is using?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, devices

How do I know which drivers my system is using (e.g. my ndiswrapper driver vs. the bundled driver)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `sudo lshw` from a terminal. This will get you extensive information on your hardware, including information about drivers.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting `vendor: Atheros Communications Inc` and `driver=ath9k driverversion=2.6.38-10-generic`... any idea if that's ndiswrapper or the original at work?

Comment: ath9k is the open source driver.

Comment: Weird. I uninstalled ndiswrapper's driver, and now I don't have any wireless at all, and I have no idea how to fix it either. (I'm writing this from Windows.) :(

Comment: Oh never mind, `sudo modprobe ath9k` fixed it. I guess that answers the question then, thanks!